# A similar constant as the Dottie number, now for the Gudermannian function and what should be your numerical strategy to calculate it

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, constants

This [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DottieNumber.html) how was defined the Dottie number. I want to know what should be a good way to define a different constant involving the Gudermannian function $\operatorname{gd}(x)$. See this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Gudermannian.html) for the definition of this special function.

**My definition** is the solution of $$1-x=\operatorname{gd}(x),\tag{1}$$

(I don't know if there is a more natural definiton) and [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com) with code

`solve gd(x)=1-x`

provide us a good approximation $$r\approx 0.51041\ldots,$$ and more digits.

> **Question.** What is a right way, and with what numerical method, to justify a good approximation of our $r$ defined as $$1-r=\operatorname{gd}(r)?$$ Isn't required the calculations, only the name of the numerical method and with what identity one should to work, *a) with the integral representation for the Gudermannian function* or well *b) with the relationship involving the inverse tangent function*? Thus I am asking about this draft: with what expression I work and with what numerical method. **Many thanks.**

Comment: If some user want do experiments with the Dottie number, one can to write *DottieNumber* in WA.

Comment: Many thanks @MichaelHardy

Comment: If this constant isn't in the literature and in future some mathematician find some interesting facts about it, I second that a good name for this consant would be using the surname of the users who answered this question. Many thanks.

Comment: @reuns Why post the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point behind the "Dottie number" is that if you iterate the cosine function, you will converge to a fixed point of that function. That is we find a solution of the equation 
$$\cos(x) = x.$$

It's important that one side be the identity. Thus, I guess the most obvious thing to do is to write your equation as 
$$1-\text{gd}(x) = x$$
and then iterate the function $f(x) = 1-\text{gd}(x)$. We can do so in WolframAlpha like by typing [`NestList[1 - Gudermannian[#] &, 1.0, 120]`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NestList%5B1+-+Gudermannian%5B%23%5D+%26,+1.0,+120%5D).

We clearly see convergence. The general topic is called [fixed point iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration) and we can expect convergence when the value of the derivative at the fixed point is less than one in absolute value - which is is in this case. In fact, the derivative of $0 < \text{gd}'(x) \leq 1$ for all $x$ so that (like the cosine) we can expect convergence to the fixed point for *all* starting values.

More precisely, if $f(x) = 1-\text{gd}(x)$, then $f'(x) \approx -0.882526$, as we can [compute on WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-Gudermannian%27%5B0.51041%5D). As a result, we expect somewhat weakly attracting fixed point. Here's an illustration:

[image]

Comment: Yes now I see that your definiton of your constant is more deep than mine. Many thanks for your contribution. I hope that some user provide some answer for my constant, and I appreciate the quality of your reasoning in the definition of your constant.

Comment: @user243301 I'm not sure what you mean by "your" constant vs the one here. They're the same, aren't they?

Comment: I'm sorry now I see that is the same numerical constant.

Answer (score 2):

Newton method will do a good job for finding the root of 
$$f(x)=1-\text{gd}(x)-x\qquad \text{and}f'(x)=-1-\text{sech}(x)$$ Using $x_0=1$ as Mark McClure did, the following iterates will be generated
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
  0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0.474671740442797381839960212004667814869157793115505244324090 \\
 2 & \color{red}{0.510}274102963764155170918024831381195730507581289697276018448 \\
 3 & \color{red}{0.510409}698618401805030200483403471453158277517329356886284684 \\
 4 & \color{red}{0.5104097006448871}29881627387868880322014411056043394900062686 \\
 5 & \color{red}{0.510409700644887130334301245058831675}184146586594448235368770 \\
 6 & \color{red}{0.510409700644887130334301245058831675206734146434315862766445}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Less iterations would be required using Halley or Householder methods.

For example, using Householder method, the following iterates will be generated
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & \color{red}{0.51}1599258877318220738741385206814044119594396507686980085584 \\
 2 & \color{red}{0.510409700644}932808766243282898431272771942065938857826177343 \\
 3 & \color{red}{0.510409700644887130334301245058831675206734146434315862}865683 \\
 4 & \color{red}{0.510409700644887130334301245058831675206734146434315862766445}
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

We could have started iterations much closer to the solution considering the $[2,2]$ Padé approximant of the considered function. Built around $x=0$ we have
$$f(x)=\frac{1-2x+\frac 1 {12}x^2} {1+\frac 1 {12}x^2 }$$ leading to an estimate $$x=2 \left(6-\sqrt{33}\right)\approx 0.510875$$

Comment: After I've read  McClure's answer I know that the only (theoretic difficulty) was to define the function $f(x)$ and then from his definition and plot one see that there is a fixed point (we've a function $f(x)$ with an intersection in the diagonal $y=x$ and the slope is well defined). A you say Newton's method works, but when I wrote the problem I was confused and I did not see this trick Many thanks to you and McClure. Aslo for your calculations and the last remarks tha will useful for professionals.